# Using evaluated variable values instead of the actual type

Tags: javascript

```
var foo;

console.log(typeof foo); //"undefined"

if(typeof foo === 'undefined')
    console.log(1);

if(!foo)
    console.log(2);
```

In my example above, the console will log both "1" and "2", since `undefined` evaluates as `false`. The same thing will happen for `null`, `NaN`, `""` (empty string) etc.

Is it more common to use the `typeof` operator and compare the string value, rather than using the evaluated boolean value? Is there any difference besides readability? Any pros and cons?

Comment: The second way will crash if the variable hasn't been declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no silver bullet and it completely depends on your aims.

If you need to know that variable is "falsy" - you use `if (!var)`, if you need to know precisely if it's `null`, `0`, empty string or whatever - you use `if (var === null)`

Comment: What about the `typeof` operator then? `typeof foo === 'null'` vs `foo === null`

Comment: @Antony The type of foo will never be "null", just "undefined" or "object" etc. The reason for using `typeof` instead of `===` is that it allows you to check for undeclared variables. `test === undefined` will throw a ReferenceError if there is no test variable, while `typeof test` will return "undefined".

Comment: I don't see the point of comparing against `null` for "null, 0, empty string or whatever". Why not use !var there as well?

Comment: @Johan sometimes you just want to make a distinction between an empty string, null or 0.

Comment: @Johan One common situation where it's common to avoid `!var` is when passing optional parameters to a function. If the parameter is undefined you will use the parameter's default value, if it's something like an empty string you will use that instead.